# Replacing light switch problem

Tags: switch

I am trying to replace a lightswitch and have run into a problem that I hope someone can help me with.

When I took the old switch off, whoever built this house, (we bought it new in 1986) wired the old switch with a black wire that is not a single hook to the side screw, but a whole wire with a portion of about 1/2 inch of the wire covering removed and the uncovered portion is "U'd around the side screw. A red wire is backstabed into the top hole.   Another black wire is/was backstabbed into the hole on the bottom next to the screw that I mentioned had the wire u'd around it.  This wire however is apparently a 12 gauge wire as opposed to the 14 gauge wire that the red wire is on top.  I know this thing is probably not wired correctly but I tried to install the new lightswitch exactly as the old one was. Replaced everything on the new switch exactly as the old one was except the apparent 12 gauge wire that was backstabbed into the old switch will not fit into the hole in the back of the new switch.  (I guess the new one only accepts 14 gauge for backstabbing.)  I really dont know how they got the 12 gauge wire into the old switch on the old one.  Anyway, it will not fit in the hole in the corresponding hole on the back of the new switch.  This wire (12 gauge black wire) that is now not connected leads into the wall in the direction of a hallway light that now does not work so I assume it goes to that or the switch that activates that hall light..  Anyone come across anything like this before?

Comment: HI Michael, a photo would be so much easier to understand.  Please edit the question and press the icon with mountains and and a dot, to add a photo

Answer (score 2):

You use a *pigtail* - a short piece of 12 AWG (15A or 20A circuit) or 14 AWG (15A circuit) wire - and a wire nut to connect the pigtail together with the two other wires. The other end of the pigtail connects to the switch in place of one of the wires.

Comment: So I can pigtail a piece of 12 awg to a 14 awg?

Comment: Only if it is a 15A circuit. If it is a 20A circuit it has to have 12 AWG everywhere.